# C++ naming mangling : QBE_NXZ QAE_NXZ

Tags: c++, dll

First of all this is all done with MS VS.

A program crash with 
"The procedure entry point ?FunName@ClassName@@QAE_NXZ could not be located in the dynamic link library XXX.dll"

I opened XXX.dll in dependency walker and all I can find is

FunName@ClassName@@QBE_NXZ , NOT FunName@ClassName@@QAE_NXZ.

I know rebuild XXX.dll would fix this but what's the difference between QBE_NXZ & QAE_NXZ?

Also is c++ name mangling is  compiler specific ?

Comment: Name mangling is indeed compiler specific.

Comment: Here you go: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Name_Mangling  --- Best of luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for the wiki link as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `undname.exe` utility that comes with Visual Studio to unmangle names. In this case:

```
C:\>undname "?FunName@ClassName@@QAE_NXZ"
Undecoration of :- "?FunName@ClassName@@QAE_NXZ"
is :- "public: bool __thiscall ClassName::FunName(void)"


C:\>undname "?FunName@ClassName@@QBE_NXZ"
Undecoration of :- "?FunName@ClassName@@QBE_NXZ"
is :- "public: bool __thiscall ClassName::FunName(void)const "
```

So as you can see the difference is whether the member function is `const` or not.

Name mangling is compiler specific. For GCC you can use the `c++filt` program to unmangle names.

Comment: Thanks this works nicely without need to looking into the big VS name mangling wiki page :) And as I suspected someone did the build without a full sync from Perforce so the const was not included and later build does have that const!